# Is it legally allowed to downgrade preinstalled Windows 11 to 10? Is it technically possible anyway?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, license, downgrade

I need to choose Computers to buy for the company I work for and most of the ones available come with Windows 11 preinstalled.

If I just do a clean Windows 10 install then, will it recognize the license on the PC or will it ask me for a key?
Is this even allowed or is the preinstalled Windows license only usable for Windows 11?

Comment: Does your company _need_ to use the preinstalled OEM licenses? Do you have any sort of Volume License agreement?

Comment: You can certainly downgrade, but in this case you should ask your Company to assist you. Manufacturers still supply computers with downgrade rights for individuals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's legal.

The Microsoft article
[Windows 11 Commercial FAQs](https://www.dandh.com/media/pdf/pages/landing-components/vendor/microsoft/Windows-11-Commercial-FAQs_FINAL.pdf)
contains this text:

> **If a remote end user purchases a Windows 11 device, can I move them back to my Windows**
>
> Downgrade rights are available with Windows 11 Pro OEM-licensed
> devices. You can downgrade to any version of Windows Pro/Professional
> that has not reached its end of support date. You will need to reimage
> or clean install a Windows 11 device to downgrade it to Windows 10.
> Downgrade rights are also available through Microsoft Volume Licensing
> (check your agreement for more details).

The text seems to say that Windows 10 will require a clean install
on top of Windows 11.
I suggest saving any device drivers specific to the
computer, or at least verify that the manufacturer supplies
these drivers.
The two Windows versions seem compatible as regarding drivers,
so Windows 11 drivers *should* install well on Windows 10
(but there is no guarantee).

The text also seems to say that the digital entitlement of the computer
from Windows 11 will also work for Windows 10, so the activation
will be automatic after the installation.
However, I suggest to activate the Windows license in Windows 11
before doing the downgrade.